# How to Capture Meeting-Created Event in MS Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

Is there a way we can capture Meeting-Created and Meeting-modified event in MS Exchange 2013 using EWS? I am very new to EWS. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EWS doesn't have events as such what you have are Async notifications, so you could get a notification when a new Item is created in the Calendar Folder or when an Item is modified. There are three different types of notifications push,pull and streaming if you want a push type notifications then streaming notification are the generally the best place to start see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx for more information.

Cheers
Glen